# CSS Override an inline style that has been automatically generated by a Google+ widget

Tags: css

Given the following HTML code generated by a Google+ widget

```
<div id="widget_bounds" class="Yfd" style="width: 290px;">
```

What should I declare in my style sheet to override the width to be 100%

I have tried the following

**Corrected typo**

```
#widget_bounds, #widget_bounds .Yfd, #widget_bounds .Yfd[style], #widget_bounds[style], .Yfd{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

and various combinations of to no avail.

Other options I have tried are

```
#widget_bounds, #widget_bounds .Yfd, .Yfd[style], #widget_bounds[style] .Yfd, #widget_bounds[style] .Yfd[style]{
    width:100% !important;
}
#widget_bounds .Yfd[style]{
    width:100% !important;
}

#widget_bounds{
    width:100% !important;
}

.Yfd[style]{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

From reading some comments I think the point has been missed that the HTML has been generated from a Google+ widget for which I only have the option to set pixel widths. I have a responsive designed website and I need to override the inline style to provide percentage widths.

Rather than down voting and voting to close a perfectly legitimate question I would appreciate it if someone is actually able to answer a difficult question.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to spell *widget* correctly.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes It is spelled correctly in my css, I made a typo in the question which was corrected. Do you have as solution? The problem remains!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was on the right tracks but it is impossible to have a Google+ widget that has a responsive design, The closest I could get to is having fixed width px values for different sized view ports.

An interesting discussion on this can be found here https://plus.google.com/+DustinStout/posts/CxL5k3EBd4x for anyone looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

**update**

As mentioned by @niels-keurentjes:

> There are a few cases where an inline style can be over-ridden, such
>   as with the !important attribute or with user style sheets.

<strike>`style="width: 290px;"` is an inline style.</strike>

from http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/qt/tipcssinlinesty.htm:

> Inline styles have the highest precedence. That means they are going
>   to be applied no matter what. The only styles that have higher
>   precedence than inline styles are user styles applied by the readers
>   themselves.

For more about the cascade: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

For this reason you can't overwrite it with CSS alternative use jQuery to reset this width:

```
$('#widget_bounds').ccs('width','100%');
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not true, `!important` does trump inline styles. It's one of the main reasons it can be useful at times. See [the last 2 lines of the very document you linked](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#preshint).

Comment: I think is not a good practice to mix inline styles with html. They should be defined in .css files, so therefore an id would have the hightest precedence.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong, I have seen this done with the Facebook Likebox Widget.

Comment: @Ioan, agreed, but I have no choice, The HTML is from a Google+ widget.

Comment: @jamesw So what ? can't you just override the styles in a .css file using an id?

Comment: @Ioan, That is exactly what I am trying to do. And it is exactly the question I am asking! How do I do it! I have even provided an example of what I have tried that does not work. I f you know how to do it then please answer the question :)

Comment: @Bass Jobsen As you can see from my question I am trying to use `width:100% !important;` But I am unable to apply it to the right style. Would you know what my css should be to resolve this? Thanks for your input. It is appreciated

Comment: post your complete html in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

The following one :

```
#widget_bounds{
   width : 100%;
}
```

Better not to use `!important` cause it breaks the natural cascading in the stylesheets.

**P.S.** You should check the spelling. The `id` is named `widget_bounds` which is different than `widet_bounds` from your css definition.

Comment: No, you have #widet_bounds. Check the spelling.

Comment: DOH! I even copid and pasted the div. Nice spot on the typo. Thanks

Comment: Corrected my question.